# XML parsing elements

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have the following XML:

```
   -<collection>
     -<beanRepresentation>
       <beanRepName>7</beanRepName>
       -<group>
         <name>John</name>
         <isFolder>true</isFolder>
        -<condition>
          <name>Normal</name>
        </condition>
       </group>
     </beanRepresentation>
   <collection>
```

I  the above XML and I want to loop through `< collection>` and get `<name>` out.
This gets the `< beanRepName>`:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation");
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("beanRepName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
}
```

But how do I get the `<name>` field inside `<group>`? i want to extract `Normal` out.

Comment: I got null from that, didnt work.

Comment: var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('name');
document.write(x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Comment: Ok that worked, thanks. But is it possible to make sure the <name> im getting is only from <condition>? Because right now, I have another field also called <name> under <group>, and it's taking that name, John instead of Normal.

Comment: does <beanRepresentation> tag repeat in collection tag

Comment: yes that's one that repeats. I also made an edit to the forloop of what I am using currently

Comment: to be more efficient we need to write program to go from root tag to name tag..using for loops..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46441/discussion-between-naren-and-jenny-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('condition');
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```